# Losing associations in nested partials in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, partials

I have a Report model that belongs_to a Location model.  When accessing a report object within a nested partial, I get a nil value for report.location when I get the desired value in the parent partial as well as in the initial view that includes the partials.

For example,

in the view for the reports/index action, I have can refer to the related locations for individual elements in a @reports array and get the desired value:

```
@reports[0].location.name # Works
```

From this view, I render a partial:

```
render :partial => "reports/reports_table", :locals => { :reports => @reports }
```

Within the reports_table partial, I can still refer to the location of an individual element of the array of reports and get a could value:

```
reports[0].location.name # Works
```

From this view, I render a partial for each individual element of the local reports array:

```
reports.each do |report|
    render :partial => "reports/report_display_row", :locals => { :report => report }
end
```

but within this second-level partial (report_display_row) I get a nil value for the associated location for each individual report:

```
report.location.name # undefined method `name' for nil:NilClass
```

I have tried variations and regardless of what I've tried, it seems in this nested partial objects associated with my instance of Report are always nil.

Comment: What do you get from report.class within the second nested partial?

Comment: there's nothing wrong here... the only possible thing I can see is that rails is getting confused over the local variable and enumerator variable being the same name. try reports.each do |r|...:report => r and see if you get the same result

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are counting on that report always has a location. Now at least one of them doesn't. Use `report.location.try(:name)` to get around the error.

If you want to make location mandatory add this validation to your report model:

```
validates :location, :presence => true
```